# Share custom taxonomy between two custom post types

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have a wordpress page with this custom post types:

- Movies
- Blurays

Movies has a custom taxonomy (genres) with movie´s genres and Blurays has a custom metabox "Belongs to movie" with movie Id.

In the blurays custom post type archive page I want to show all the genres and count blurays by them.

This is working now in http://sinentradas.com/comprar-peliculas-80/

But this is because both custom post types have genre custom taxonomy and I want one of this posibilities:

- Only movies has it and using metabox "Belongs to movie" show all the bluray filtered by movies genres.
- Share custom taxonomy without repeat it in both custom post types.

I tried creating a custom taxonomy "genrebr" but if a genrebr doesnt exists it generates a 404.

Is possible that I try?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you want:

- get all movies that belong to a bluray
- get the custom_taxonomy from the movie

you can fetch the movies (and get their post_id) and then use wp_get_post_terms() to fetch the custom_taxonomy

```
wp_get_post_terms($movie_post_id, 'custom_taxonomy', array("fields" => "ids"));
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms

Comment: Hi,

I need a workaround for attach genres to bluray based on film that  belongs. And I need a file (slug) to visualizate blurays by genre. If I add custom taxonomy (genre) to bluray i will fix it, but then, i would have duplicated this info in both blurays and movies custom post type. Do you understand me?

Comment: In my approach, you do the following: 1. assign a genre to a movie, 2.) assign movie to blueray, 3) read all movies 4) get all genres of movies... otherwise, I don't get your point

Comment: Thanks for your response... The point is that I have to show it in archive-bluray.php file... So 1,2 is ok but I think that it would be... 3) read all blurays and 4) get all genres from movies that belongs to each bluray... The next problem is how (and in what file) show blurays filtered by genre... For example I want a slug like that "/buy-blurays/genre/action" without genre taxonomy for blurays. Is it possible?

Comment: Of course, you can do that, but it's a little bit more complicated: you'll have to use a combination of custom-sql-queries and custom-redirects: http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-to-creating-redirects-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks... Another possibility would be use an unique url for blurays /buy-blurays/ and  show each genre as a link... when you click on it... reload page with genre parameter and perform a new query with this genre ... Its a more easy approach, isnt?

Comment: yeah, but you would have to associate the `/bluray/somegenre` with a variable, so therefore you'll need a custom redirect, like a`blueray/somegenre`with `blueray?genre=somegenre` and handle `$_GET['genre']` in your code.

Comment: oh, you mean you could live with `/blueray?genre=somegenre` then of course you can